# What does it mean to have two intercepts?

Tags: regression, interaction, intercept

Suppose I am modeling the sales for multiple products for multiple stores. What is the difference between:
\begin{align}
\text{Sales} &= \beta_{0}(\text{Intercept × Store}) +\beta_{1}(\text{Intercept × Product})  \\
&\text{and}  \\
\text{Sales} &= \beta_{0}(\text{Intercept × Store}\times\text{Product}) 
\end{align}
What is the difference between these two regressions?

Comment: Despite using $\beta_0$, you don't have any intercepts listed. You have *slope* coefficients in these models. In addition, you have the same slope coefficient for both variables in the first model. Are you sure these represent what you are really after? For reference, consider the simplest model encompassing both of these:$$\text{Sales}=\beta_{0}+\beta_1\text{Intercept}+\beta_2\text{Store}+\beta_3(\text{Intercept*Store}) +\beta_{1}(\text{Intercept*Product})$$

Comment: I made some edits.

Comment: *The timer cut off my edit, the formula is supposed to read:* $$\text{Sales} = \beta_{0} + \beta_1\text{Product} + \beta_2\text{Store} + \beta_3(\text{Product} * \text{Store})$$

Comment: Unfortunately, the new models don't make much sense to me either. The $\text{Intercept}$ will have no effect on anything, b/c it is just a constant that everything is multiplied by. That is, the fitted slopes, $\beta_j$ will be scaled down by a factor of $1/\text{Intercept}$. There is still no intercept in these models, ie they will all have $\text{Sales}=0$ at $\text{Store}=\text{Product}=0$. It will help more if you can clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Not intending offense, but I think you need to take a course in regression modeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bunch wrong with both of these, and neither one involves two intercepts, in fact, neither has even one intercept.

The difference is that the first one forces a model with no intercept to have the same parameter for both independent variables while the latter ignores the main effects and includes only the interaction.

What's wrong?

1. You need a multi-level model because data will be dependent.
2. The second model includes an interaction but not the main effects
3. The first model forces both parameters to be the same